# Run Shiny-server on different port than 3838

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, shiny-server

I am deploying Shiny-server in container. By default Shiny-server listens on port 3838, here is piece from shiny-server.conf

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;
```

I would like to change this port to 80. I obviously can launch container instance, login to it, and change it, but I would like to change it in Dockerfile.

```
FROM rocker/shiny:3.5.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libv8-3.14-dev -y &&\
  mkdir -p /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmarks/shiny

# Download and install library
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shinydashboard', 'shinyjs', 'V8'))"

# copy the app to the image COPY shinyapps /srv/shiny-server/
COPY "reports" "/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps/reports/"

# make all app files readable (solves issue when dev in Windows, but building in Ubuntu)
RUN chmod -R 755 /srv/shiny-server/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Is there command line option for final line in Dockerfile?

Comment: `RUN sed -i -e 's/\blisten 3838\b/listen 80/g' /path/to/shiny-server.conf`?

Comment: Alternatively, I like to keep mine at 3838, and when I run it, the port is mapped externally, as in `docker --ports "80:3838" ...` (or whatever the cli args are).

Comment: @r2evans, thank you, I am planning to deploy it on Azure. Azure docker implementation does not port mapping afaik.

Comment: @r2evans, you first comment worked, you can posted as the solution and I will accept. I tried to create copy of shiny-server.conf file and edit it and then copy, but it got overwritten somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```docker
RUN sed -i -e 's/\blisten 3838\b/listen 80/g' /path/to/shiny-server.conf
```

So perhaps ending up with:

```docker
FROM rocker/shiny:3.5.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libv8-3.14-dev -y &&\
  mkdir -p /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmarks/shiny

# Download and install library
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shinydashboard', 'shinyjs', 'V8'))"

# copy the app to the image COPY shinyapps /srv/shiny-server/
COPY "reports" "/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps/reports/"

# make all app files readable (solves issue when dev in Windows, but building in Ubuntu)
RUN chmod -R 755 /srv/shiny-server/

RUN sed -i -e 's/\blisten 3838\b/listen 80/g' /path/to/shiny-server.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

(I know multiple layers can be inefficient if not compacted, over to you if you want to combine the `sed` line with the previous `RUN` command. You might want to combine more of those `RUN` lines, if that's a concern.)